# How do I download a file over HTTP using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, download

How do I download a file over HTTP using Ruby?

Answer (score 26):

Probably the shortest way to download a file:

```
require 'open-uri'
download = URI.open('http://example.com/')
IO.copy_stream(download, './my_file.html')
```

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, this solution Just Worked. You might consider answering this here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http

Comment: Does not work with more recent versions of ruby. Use `URI.open` instead of `open`.

Answer (score 14):

```
require 'net/http'
#part of base library
Net::HTTP.start("your.webhost.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/yourfile.xml")
  open("yourfile.xml", "wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use open-uri, which is a one liner

```
require 'open-uri'

content = open('http://example.com').read
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple...

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("yourURI"))
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways, but the easiest is probably [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/). [This blog post](http://juretta.com/log/2006/08/13/ruby_net_http_and_open-uri/) has some sample code, and also goes over Net::HTTP (with Hpricot) and Rio.

Comment: The easiest, and the most dangerous. OpenURI patches Kernel#open, and if any user input ever gets close to the string you're about to open, the door is open for both reading any file on the system and remote code execution.

Comment: You can consider [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647221/ruby-nethttpget-and-json-responses#comment122667651_3647237) for more information. Quoting: "Note unless you can be certain the url cannot have been maliciously crafted (e.g. by user input) something like `content = URI.parse('http://your_url.com').read` is safer. See http://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_security.html#securityopen "