# How can I download a file from a URL and save it in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-handling

I have a URL to an image which i want to save locally, so that I can use Paperclip to produce a thumbnail for my application. What's the best way to download and save the image? (I looked into ruby file handling but did not come across anything.)

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://example.com/image.png').read
end
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. I tried this on an image. The image was not properly written to the file. As if it has been corrupted or something. Also could you guide me to do this same in a Rails application. Can i use this in a Rails application ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in a rails application. The file not being written properly is probably because I forgot to open the destination in write-binary mode. I'll edit that now.

Comment: This reads the whole file in memory. The best way is `IO.copy_stream(open('http://example.com/image.png'), 'destination.png')`

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I've created a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071931/how-to-save-image-from-url-to-local-ubuntu-folder-from-rails-console

Comment: rails 5, 2016, I didn't need to `require 'open-uri'`, just used the code under it

Comment: this answer did not work for me. correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29743394/1536309

Comment: Is it possible to provide a path of where the file should be stored? Currently, is being stored on root in Rails app

Comment: Extreme caution if the url can be provided by the user! https://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html

Answer (score 187):

An even shorter version:

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open('http://example.com/image.png')
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/image.png')
```

To keep the same filename:

```
IO.copy_stream(download, "~/#{download.base_uri.to_s.split('/')[-1]}")
```

Comment: And more efficient as the output is not stored as a string in memory. +1

Comment: Though it's actually useful having both answers displayed, so people like me can see both, think about the differences and then choose this answer consciously for the right reasons :)

Comment: I'm getting a security warning from Rubocop when using `open`. I replaced it with `URI.parse(url).open` instead. Read more about that cop here: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Security/Open

Comment: pure `open` does not work for me, had to use `URI.open`

Answer (score 32):

If you're using PaperClip, downloading from a URL is now handled automatically.

Assuming you've got something like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, ...
end
```

On your model, just specify the image as a URL, something like this (written in deliberate longhand):

```
@my_model = MyModel.new
image_url = params[:image_url]
@my_model.image = URI.parse(image_url)
```

You'll probably want to put this in a method in your model. This will also work just fine on Heroku's temporary filesystem.

Paperclip will take it from there.

source: [paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL)

Comment: For future searchers, Paperclip no longer allows this by default: https://medium.com/in-the-weeds/all-about-paperclips-cve-2017-0889-server-side-request-forgery-ssrf-vulnerability-8cb2b1c96fe8

Answer (score 19):

I think this is the clearest way:

```
require 'open-uri'

File.write 'image.png', open('http://example.com/image.png').read
```

Comment: sage i am new to rails, where i can add this code in model or controller or in view

Comment: It depends, but typically you'd do something like this inside a model or controller method. In a Rails context, you're likely better off using the framework's tools like ActiveStorage, rather than writing directly to disk.

Answer (score 13):

Possibly the simplest way:

```
require 'open-uri'
image_url = "https://i.imgur.com/ZWnhY9T.png"
IO.copy_stream(URI.open(image_url), 'destination.png')
```

Comment: In my situation, I tried all the codes above. only this floor worked. The difference is copy_stream()'s first param **URI.open(img_url)**, if i dont wrap the `img_url` by `URI.open()`, i got the following ERROR `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the download progress?

Comment: @Pioz sorry I don't know of a way, however it could make a great question to ask, as I suspect it would be valuable to others too. Please drop the link here if you ask it.

Comment: I was able to do it in this gist: https://gist.github.com/pioz/504f32c58465d56b12e01a2c4de05ab6#file-one_piece_downloader-rb-L21

Answer (score 11):

Check out [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) in the standard library.  The documentation provides several examples on how to download documents using HTTP.

Comment: This answer needs more visibility as `Kernel#open` enables not only file access but also process invocation by prefixing a pipe symbol (e.g., `open("| ls")`). So, it may lead to a serious security risk by using variable input to the argument of `Kernel#open`.

Answer (score 4):

Using Ruby 3 and above, you'll get the following error using the accepted answer:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://example.com/image.png (Errno::ENOENT)

The solution is to use `URI.open` in place of the `Kernel.open`. Example:

```
require "uri"

download = URI.open('http://example.com/image.png')
File.write('~/image.png', download)
```

Answer (score 0):

All above examples are great.
In my case I just wanted to create a download link from the image from URL.

If you want to make it downloadable (to your downloads folder), you can use the following code in your controller:

```
require 'open-uri'
file_type = url.to_s.split(".")[-1]

send_data open(url).read, filename: "some_name.#{file_type}", type: "image/#{file_type}", disposition: "attachment"
```