# Best way to download and process images during user data import feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a feature where users bulk import data via CSV.  The CSV can have image URLs nested in it.  How can I grab the images via the given URLs and post them to my site?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, Paperclip w/ S3 as my backend.

Thanks for reading and possibly helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have all the logic to parse the CSV and get the URL (if not, look into either [csv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) in the standard library or [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html)).  To grab the file you could:

- Use Net::HTTP (see [this page](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2469))
- Use open-uri (which I guess is really just a wrapper for Net::HTTP, but I prefer the syntax (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/i-want-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-to-save-it-any-rails-way-to-do-this-or-can)))
- Call off to [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to grab the file for you (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby) if calling command line programs from Ruby is a question)

After that, I suppose it's simply a matter of putting a tag on a page and pointing to wherever you saved the file.