# Ruby - open("file_path") - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby

I keep getting this `No such file or directory` error when trying to open a file. I'm doing:

`file = open("http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6064/6090089285_242ca0e342_m.jpg")` according to the [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) and keep getting such error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to download a file from a URL to save it. Any Rails way to do this or can I do with Ruby File Handling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/i-want-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-to-save-it-any-rails-way-to-do-this-or-can)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to

```
require 'open-uri'
```

Without requiring 'open-uri', I got this exact error mesage in my irb: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`