# Need to download a file from amazon s3 to local folder?

Tags: amazon-s3, download, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3.11 and i want to download a file from amazon s3 into my local folder.How can i achieve that?please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK amazon s3 objects (files) have unique URLs. Once you have the s3 object URL you can use standard ruby code to download it and save to a local folder as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/i-want-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-to-save-it-any-rails-way-to-do-this-or-can).

Comment: they above solution is working for to get file from amazon thank you.

Comment: Is that possible for me to store the file into scribd account using amazon s3 url without storing it in local?

Comment: If you are using the scribd API it's possible to upload a document using a URL ([api reference]http://www.scribd.com/developers/platform/api/docs_uploadfromurl).