# How do I user UserMailer in Rails to send a file stored on AWS with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, file-upload, amazon-web-services

The command File.read(file_url) in the code below won't work because I'm trying to pull down a file such as (example - file_url= 'http://placecorgi.com/100/100.pdf') which is not a file but a file on a server.

What do I need to change to pull down this file from AWS and send through UserMailer?

```
  class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
         def send_user_pages(user, file_url)
            @user = user
            attachments["user_pages.pdf"] = File.read(file_url)
            mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Your Pages')
          end
   end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-a-url-and-save-it-in-rails

Comment: Hi BMW - Is that process async?

Comment: Do you mean the pdf keep updated?

Comment: where would I add the line `attachments["user_pages.pdf"] = File.read(file_url)` in the code...`open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://example.com/image.png').read
end` \n After? in the block? I can't seem to get it to work