# Replace entire file in directory with file at URL endpoint in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

Let's say I have the following file in my working directory:

```
path/to/my/file/fileToBeReplaced.json
```

And I have a file at the following URL endpoint:

```
mywebsite.com/fileToCopy.json
```

I want to take the file at the URL endpoint (fileToCopy.json) and fetch the contents there to overwrite the file in my working directory (fileToBeReplaced.json). It's also important that I *preserve the json formatting* when writing the file to my working directory. How can this be accomplished within a Ruby script?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-a-url-and-save-it-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
require 'net/http'

File.open("path/to/my/file/fileToBeReplaced.json", "w") do |f|
   f.write Net::HTTP.get('mywebsite.com', '/fileToCopy.json')
end
```

If your JSON from URL is not well formatted, then, you can try something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

File.open("path/to/my/file/fileToBeReplaced.json", "w") do |f|
   json_str = Net::HTTP.get('mywebsite.com', '/fileToCopy.json')
   json_hash = JSON.parse(json_str)
   f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(json_hash)
end
```

Comment: This works but doesn't preserve the json formatting. I've tried adding "to_json" to the end of the f.write line, but it just inserts /'s in place of white space.

Comment: Hmm... I got the file with formatting preserved.   Does your URL return JSON with formatting ?   Updated my answer to show usage of `JSON#pretty_generate`

Comment: It looks like I was using Ruby 1.8 for this. The hash function is undefined in 1.8, but is insertion order for 1.9, so upgrading fixed this issue.