# How to verify that IO.copy_stream was successful

Tags: ruby

A great answer here explains how, in Ruby, to download a file without loading it into memory:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29743394/4852737

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open('http://example.com/image.png')
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/image.png')
```

How would I verify that the IO.copy_stream call to download the file was actually successful — meaning that the downloaded file is the exact same file I intended to download, not a half downloaded corrupt file? The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-copy_stream) says that IO.copy_stream returns the number of bytes that it copied, but how can I know the number of bytes expected when I have not downloaded the file yet?

Comment: What does success mean to you? That the right number of bytes are on the disk? That the file is a valid file of its type? Something else?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Sorry I thought it would be self explanatory. That the downloaded file is an exact copy of the file at the url. I would automatically think cksum but I know that isnt possible. So maybe the only option is to verify that the size of the files match?

Comment: You should be careful here: servers are not required to return 'Content-Length' in the headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenURI `open` returns an object which exposes the HTTP response's headers, so you can get the expected byte count from the Content-Length header and compare it to the return value of `IO.copy_stream`:

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png'
bytes_expected = download.meta['content-length']
bytes_copied = IO.copy_stream download, 'image.png'
if bytes_expected != bytes_copied
  raise "Expected #{bytes_expected} bytes but got #{bytes_copied}"
end
```

It would be surprising if `open` executed without error and this check still failed, but you never know.