# How to save image from url to local ubuntu folder from rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to write image parser from some website which will take images, some other info and save it to my local folder.
So let's say we have image at this url :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg
(this is someone's SO avatar)

So I want to to save it to local folder. Let's say to `"~/test/image.png"`
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-a-url-and-save-it-in-rails)

And I tried this in my terminal:

```
rails console

require 'open-uri'
  open('~/test/image.jpg', 'wb') do
  |file| file << open('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg').read
end
```

As you  can see my home/test folder is empty 
[image]

And I got this output from console 
`#<File:~/test/image.jpg (closed)>`[image]

What do I do?

Also I tried this:

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg')
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/test/image.jpg')
```

And got this output:

> => #https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg>, @meta={"date"=>"Fri, 06 May 2016
>   11:58:05 GMT", "content-type"=>"image/jpeg", "content-length"=>"4276",
>   "connection"=>"keep-alive",
>   "set-cookie"=>"__cfduid=d7f982c0742bf40e58d626659c65a88841462535885;
>   expires=Sat, 06-May-17 11:58:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.imgur.com;
>   HttpOnly", "cache-control"=>"public, max-age=315360000",
>   "etag"=>"\"b75caf18a116034fc3541978de7bac5b\"", "expires"=>"Mon, 04
>   May 2026 11:58:05 GMT", "last-modified"=>"Thu, 28 Mar 2013 15:05:35
>   GMT", "x-amz-version-id"=>"TP7cpPcf0jWeW2t1gUz66VXYlevddAYh",
>   "cf-cache-status"=>"HIT", "vary"=>"Accept-Encoding",
>   "server"=>"cloudflare-nginx", "cf-ray"=>"29ec4221fdbf267e-FRA"},
>   @metas={"date"=>["Fri, 06 May 2016 11:58:05 GMT"],
>   "content-type"=>["image/jpeg"], "content-length"=>["4276"],
>   "connection"=>["keep-alive"],
>   "set-cookie"=>["__cfduid=d7f982c0742bf40e58d626659c65a88841462535885;
>   expires=Sat, 06-May-17 11:58:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.imgur.com;
>   HttpOnly"], "cache-control"=>["public, max-age=315360000"],
>   "etag"=>["\"b75caf18a116034fc3541978de7bac5b\""], "expires"=>["Mon, 04
>   May 2026 11:58:05 GMT"], "last-modified"=>["Thu, 28 Mar 2013 15:05:35
>   GMT"], "x-amz-version-id"=>["TP7cpPcf0jWeW2t1gUz66VXYlevddAYh"],
>   "cf-cache-status"=>["HIT"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"],
>   "server"=>["cloudflare-nginx"], "cf-ray"=>["29ec4221fdbf267e-FRA"]},
>   @status=["200", "OK"]> 
>   2.3.0 :244 > IO.copy_stream(download, '~/test/image.jpg')  => 4276
>   [image]

But my folder is still empty.
What do I do??

Comment: I don't know if it suits your use case, but the carrierwave gem makes this quite easy for users (if you want users to upload their avatar for instance). https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location

Comment: @Matt I don't have any users at all. =) I am writing an image parser

Comment: try replacing `~` with `/home/yourusername/`

Comment: @MladenJablanović  It says `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - home/jonstark/test/image.jpg`

Comment: @MladenJablanović sorry I wrote `home/jonstark` and it gave me an error. Then I wrote `/home/jonstark/` with `/` before `home` and it worked! write it as an answer! i will accept it=)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the file is not getting created. If you create the file using `File.open` or `open` and then execute the `IO.copy_stream' it will work.

Also `~/` doesn't work in ruby. You have to specify the whole path.

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg')
open('/home/user/image.jpg', 'w')
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/test/image.jpg')
```

If you want a directory to be created as well, you will have to user `Dir.mkdir`. If you want to create nested directories use `FileUtils::mkdir_p`. If it is difficult to use either, I would suggest using `system 'mkdir dirname'` or `system 'mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3'`

```
Dir.mkdir '/home/user/test' # doesnt work for nested folder creation

require 'fileutils'
FileUtils::mkdir_p '/home/user/test1/test2' # for nested

system 'mkdir '~/test'   # Unix command for directory creation
system 'mkdir -p '~/test1/test2'   # Unix command for nested directory
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, could you just use the `wget`?

You can use both `wget 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg'` and `system("wget 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg'")`. Or `system("wget 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqEv.jpg' > /your/path`

Note: for the first command you need to wrap you command into the ` signs. This will cause ruby to call a system command.

Also, consider using `/home/your_name` instead of just `~`. Also notice the leading `/` slash.