# How can I download an internet image from a URL and save it in locally in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I download an internet image from a URL and save it in locally in Rails?

i give a form to add image url [form link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrEBQ.png) if i submit that form i want to download image to computer local disk (Home/Documents/food_img)

pls need help

in downloads controller

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @downloads = Download.all
        @download = Download.new
    end

    def create
        @download = Download.create(user_params)
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:download).permit(:image,:image_url)
    end
end
```

in view/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@download, url: downloads_path) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :image_url %>
<%=f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

in model

```
class Download < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

    require 'open-uri'
    download = open('http://www.shopprod.com/assets/photos/ishop-718755d2bc62956994c867681b2622e77b4c9af3d1ecd6fa856127b704a459b2.png')
    IO.copy_stream(download, "~/#{download.base_uri.to_s.split('/')[-1]}")
end
```

in db

```
t.string: image_url
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a file from a URL and save it in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515931/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-a-url-and-save-it-in-rails)

Comment: @tadman need help pls

Comment: @anothermh need help pls

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you need help then you need to ask a specific question. It's not enough to say you're confused and post a bunch of code. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @anothermh i edit my question ,pls need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [ActiveStorage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) (which I would recommend) you can use [`.attach`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) to attach an IO stream to a record.

given:

```
class Download < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

From the rails console you can download a file and attach it with:

```
require 'open-uri'
uri = 'http://www.shopprod.com/assets/photos/ishop-718755d2bc62956994c867681b2622e77b4c9af3d1ecd6fa856127b704a459b2.png'
download = Download.new
download.image.attach(io: open(uri), filename: uri.split('/').last)
```

However you can't just toss it whilly-nilly into your model class and expect it to work. The class body is executed when the class is read.

Instead you need to put it into a method and call it at the correct point.

```
class Download < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  def download_image!
    require 'open-uri'
    image.attach(
      io: open(self.image_url), 
      filename: self.image_url.split('/').last
    )
  end
end
```

---

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @download = Download.new(download_params)
    if !@download.image.attached? && @download.image_url
      @download.download_image!
      # @todo handle errors 
    end
    if @download.save
      redirect_to @download
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def download_params
    params.require(:download)
          .permit(:image, :image_url)
  end
end
```

Comment: i install activestorage using(rails active_storage:install) and then give a form to add url <%= form_for(@download, url: downloads_path) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :image_url %>
<%=f.submit%>
<% end %> but it not storing image,It storing only image data
 tanks for help me, but i want image should store local dick(computer).

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#disk-service