# Download an image from a URL?

Tags: ruby, httpwebrequest, javax.imageio

I am trying to use HTTP::get to download an image of a Google chart from a URL I created.

This was my first attempt:

```
failures_url  = [title, type, data, size, colors, labels].join("&")

require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start("http://chart.googleapis.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/chart?#{failures_url")
  open("pie.png" ,"wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  }
}
```

Which produced only an empty PNG file.

For my second attempt I used the value stored inside `failure_url` inside the `http.get()` call.

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start("http://chart.googleapis.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/chart?chtt=Builds+in+the+last+12+months&cht=bvg&chd=t:296,1058,1217,1615,1200,611,2055,1663,1746,1950,2044,2781,1553&chs=800x375&chco=4466AA&chxl=0:|Jul-2010|Aug-2010|Sep-2010|Oct-2010|Nov-2010|Dec-2010|Jan-2011|Feb-2011|Mar-2011|Apr-2011|May-2011|Jun-2011|Jul-2011|2:|Months|3:|Builds&chxt=x,y,x,y&chg=0,6.6666666666666666666666666666667,5,5,0,0&chxp=3,50|2,50&chbh=23,5,30&chxr=1,0,3000&chds=0,3000")
  open("pie.png" ,"wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  }
}
```

And, for some reason, this version works even though the first attempt had the same data inside the `http.get()` call. Does anyone know why this is?

SOLUTION:

After trying to figure why this is happening I found "[How do I download a binary file over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http-using-ruby)".

One of the comments mentions removing `http://` in the `Net::HTTP.start(...)` call otherwise it won't succeed. Sure enough after I did this:

```
failures_url  = [title, type, data, size, colors, labels].join("&")

require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start("chart.googleapis.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/chart?#{failures_url")
  open("pie.png" ,"wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  }
}
```

it worked.

Comment: You're missing a `File.` before `open("pie.png"...`

Comment: Over a yeah old, but google did not forget about it... it's good to keep SO updated

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'd go after the file using Ruby's [Open::URI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames):

```
require "open-uri"

File.open('pie.png', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write open("http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?#{failures_url}").read 
end
```

The reason I prefer Open::URI is it handles redirects automatically, so WHEN Google makes a change to their back-end and tries to redirect the URL, the code will handle it magically. It also handles timeouts and retries more gracefully if I remember right.

If you must have lower level control then I'd look at one of the many other HTTP clients for Ruby; Net::HTTP is fine for creating new services or when a client doesn't exist, but I'd use Open::URI or something besides Net::HTTP until the need presents itself.

---

The URL:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chtt=Builds+in+the+last+12+months&cht=bvg&chd=t:296,1058,1217,1615,1200,611,2055,1663,1746,1950,2044,2781,1553&chs=800x375&chco=4466AA&chxl=0:|Jul-2010|Aug-2010|Sep-2010|Oct-2010|Nov-2010|Dec-2010|Jan-2011|Feb-2011|Mar-2011|Apr-2011|May-2011|Jun-2011|Jul-2011|2:|Months|3:|Builds&chxt=x,y,x,y&chg=0,6.6666666666666666666666666666667,5,5,0,0&chxp=3,50|2,50&chbh=23,5,30&chxr=1,0,3000&chds=0,3000
```

makes URI upset. I suspect it is seeing characters that should be encoded in URLs.

For documentation purposes, here is what URI says when trying to parse that URL as-is:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)
```

If I encode the URI first, I get a successful parse. Testing further using Open::URI shows it is able to retrieve the document at that point and returns 23701 bytes.

I think that is the appropriate fix for the problem if some of those characters are truly not acceptable to URI *AND* they are out of the RFC.

Just for information, the [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem is a great replacement for the built-in URI.

Comment: this was one of the things i tried initialy, but URI.parse doesnt like the format of the google URLs. The call results in Bad URL(is not URI?) error message

Comment: I duplicated the error by concatenating your full URL. Ruby's URI has some known problems, but in this case, some of the characters in the URL need to be encoded. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: In my case I had to call `URI.open` explicitly instead of just `open`

Answer (score 3):

```
    resp = http.get("/chart?#{failures_url")
```

If you copied your original code then you're missing a closing curly bracket in your path string.

Comment: if that is the problem I may yell very loudly. The code is at work so I cant check until the morning. Thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Your original version did not have the parameter name for each parameter, just the data. For example, on the title, you cannot just submit "Builds+in+the+last+12+months", but instead it must be "chtt=Builds+in+the+last+12+months".

Try this:

```
failures_url  = ["title="+title, "type="+type, "data="+data, "size="+size, "colors="+colors, "labels="+labels].join("&")
```

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean, the data is stored in a variable called `failures_url`

Comment: I just added a bit more to the answer. See if that helps.

Comment: the original version does have the parameter names also, they are just stored in the variable. The string I used in my second attempt is the literal value of `failures_url`

Comment: Parameters will be a key-value pair is what he means, not just a list of values..

Comment: @Hunter: You mean at some point you coded: `title = "title=Builds in the last 12 months"` ?

Comment: Yes, title = "chtt=Builds+in+the+last+12+months", I do all of that processing before this.