# Paperclip pictures uploaded with URL doesn't get stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, omniauth-facebook

I'm using paperclip to store pictures on Amazon S3.
It works fine if I upload via a normal form, but I also want to set users' profile pictures to their facebook picture by default if they are registering with facebook via omniauth.

It sets the picture file size, the name and all the other fields properly. It even sets the correct link when I call

```
 <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:small) %>
```

But for some reason the image does not get stored.

Again, if I upload with a form it uploads the picture fine.

```
  <%= f.label :profile_picture %>
  <%= f.file_field :profile_picture %>
```

How I try to parse the image from the link on registration:

```
user.profile_picture=URI.parse(auth.info.image)
```

My paperclip configuration:

```
  has_attached_file :profile_picture, styles: { small: "150x150>" },
                    path: "app/public/uploads/profile_pictures/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  validates_attachment_size :profile_picture, less_than: 2.megabytes
```

My production.rb:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
  }
```

Paperclip.rb initializer:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Comment: you should search for how to downloading images given a url in ruby. quick google returns this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768238/download-an-image-from-a-url

Comment: I used the method from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip