# Get image from parsing the response

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get an image from the response body. Right now this gives me the entire HTML page. I see the  tag but cannot specifically retrieve it. Any help would be great!

```
#Get Request
encoded_response = response.body.force_encoding("UTF-8")
url = URI.parse(encoded_response)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.img
```

For those about to ask, I had to encode the response because I was getting a Bad URI errorIP

Comment: Could you show your response body, please?

Comment: @Stefan added it to the post

Comment: And could you show its content, too?

Comment: @Stefan I substituted out some private info. Hope that's enough.

Comment: I'm interested in the response body, i.e. `response.body`. You say that it contains the "entire HTML page" and that you can "see the tag" but I can't see anything :-)

Comment: @Stefan hmm... Interesting. For me when I run the ruby file in the terminal I get the entire HTML document and within it I see an <IMG SRC="_TMP.png">. I'm not sure what else to give ya.. haha

Comment: There's only one `<img>` element?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at a parsing library like [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)?

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(response.body.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
image_urls = html.css('img').map { |image_tag| image_tag["src"] }
```

For "downloading" the image, see here: [Download an image from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768238/download-an-image-from-a-url)