# Download a file from a website to a server using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

How can I download a file located on a remote website (a download link is available or an address to an actual file on the remote server) to the server running the rails application? The file needs to be stored in a specific folder in the server file system.

Comment: It depends, would you like the users to submit the remote file's urls?

Comment: It is a fixed location, I have it as a string

Comment: Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http-using-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it step by step:

1. Use the [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

   in your Gemfile:

   `gem 'carrierwave'`
2. in your view

   `<%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>`
3. in your model

   `attr_accessible :remote_image_url`

More detail you can check Ryan's railscast[#253 CarrierWave File Uploads](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) as an upload plugin and use its **Uploading files from a remote location** feature to upload something via a URL.