# Download and extract .tbz file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, extract

Is there a ruby gem/library that can extra `.tbz` files?

This will specifically be within a Rails app, if that's relevant.

I've aware of Rubyzip for `.zip` files, but haven't found a way to extract `.tbz` files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [bzip2-ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby) gem for decompressing it to a tar?

You can then use [archive-tar-minitar](http://rubygems.org/gems/archive-tar-minitar) to untar it.

In the subject, you ask about downloading -- but you don't repeat that in your actual question. [Here's a question about downloading within a Ruby script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http-using-ruby)