# Download File/Image as binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, download, binary

I'm searching for a way to download an URL with an image as binary so I can BASE64 Encode it and send it to my SAP Database. All this using RAILS.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http

Comment: Well that's all about writing files, can't you just read an online URL instead of working with HTTP

Comment: I think this could work: open(params[:linkedin_pic], 'rb')

Comment: Will the above really download the file or just the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried different things, I think the Curb gem is the best solution. 
This gem is found here: [Ruby Gems Curb](https://rubygems.org/gems/curb)

It was easy to use like this:

```
curl_profile_pic = Curl::Easy.perform("example.url.jpeg)
params["personal_info"]["profile_pic"] = Base64.encode64(curl_profile_pic.body_str)
```