# Watir - How to save a pdf file when the file opens in html

Tags: html, pdf, browser, save, watir

When I click on a link, the pdf opens in the browser. My test requires me to save the pdf onto the desktop.

I was able to locate the new window where the pdf is opened but unable to save. As to save the pdf, i have to either hover the mouse on the bottom to get the pdf icon or I will have to go to file-> Save as to save the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

here is [sample code](http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-downloads/) of how you can do it in firefox

```
download_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads"
download_directory.gsub!("/", "\\") if Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.windows?

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2 # custom location
profile['browser.download.dir'] = download_directory
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

and Chrome

```
download_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads"
download_directory.gsub!("/", "\\") if  Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.windows?

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = download_directory

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

with ie you will probably have to do something like this:

```
f = open('sample.pdf')
begin
    http.request_get('/sample.pdf') do |resp|
        resp.read_body do |segment|
            f.write(segment)
        end
    end
ensure
    f.close()
end
```

[Code Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http)

Comment: I need this for IE browser. Let me know if there is any way.

Comment: I tried to save the pdf using File -> Save AS toolbar. So sent the keys to click on file -> Save As

Comment: @browser.send_keys([:control,:shift,'s']) --Control+Shift+S

Comment: @browser.send_keys([:alt,'fa']) --Alt+F+A keys