# How can I avoid redirecting when try to download a file using wget or curl?

Tags: ruby, url, curl, download, wget

I'm trying to get/download some files from an url. I'm make a tiny script in ruby to get this files. Follow the script:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

(1..2).each do |season|
  (1..3).each do |ep|
    season = season.to_s.rjust(2, '0')
    ep = ep.to_s.rjust(2, '0')

    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://some-url/s#{season}e{ep}/releases"))
    page.css('table.table tbody tr td a').each do |el|
      link = el['href']
      `curl "https://some-url#{link}"` if link.match('sujaidr.srt$')
    end
  end
end
puts "done"
```

But the response from `curl` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: 
<a href="/some-url/friends-s0Xe0Y/releases">/some-url/s0Xe0Y/releases</a>.  If not click the link.
```

When I use `wget` the redirected page is downloaded. I tried to set the user agent but not works. The server always redirect the link only when I try download the files through `curl` or others cli's like `wget`, `aria2c`, `httpie`, etc. And I can't find any solution for now.

How can I do this?

---

## Solved

I decide use [Watir](http://watir.com/) webdriver to do this. Works great for now.

Comment: Sounds like a header or cookie is missing.

Comment: Wget follows redirects automatically. Are you sure wget is not just following the redirect and then downloading?

Comment: @Casper, thats the point. Wget follows the redirect and download the html page redirected not the file what I want. Understand?

Comment: I try using `curl -L --max-redirs 0` options but returns the this `curl: (47) Maximum (0) redirects followed`. I know the [`-L` option tells the Curl to follows the HTTP redirects](https://ec.haxx.se/http-redirects.html). But if without it the Curl return the html page that I've been cited.

Comment: If the server responds with a redirect, then the file is not there. You can't download it, if the server doesn't provide it at that address. This is not a problem of not following redirects, this is a problem of the server responding with a redirect instead of what you are expecting. I would debug this with a browser and its network monitor first. If you download it with the browser, is it being redirected too? This should be visible in the browser debugger.

Comment: Some websites protect their download links with JavaScript in order to make scraping harder. My guess is you might be running into an issue like that (unless it's a cookie issue, like Stefan commented).

Comment: @Casper, answer you question "If you download it with the browser, is it being redirect too?": If I copy the file link address using the inspect devtools and paste in to the address bar, it is being redirect. But if I click on button to download file, it is not redirect and download the file.

Comment: @Casper, I think you are right about the website protecting their download links with JS. When I inspect the html element, the link is under an `onclick` event. I'm not found a way to work around the problem yet.

Comment: You want to look into using a headless browser setup like PhantomJS. This will run the JavaScript inside a virtual browser that you can control through Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the file, rather then the page doing the redirection try using the option `-L` within your code for example:

```
curl -L "https://some-url#{link}"
```

From the `curl` man:

```
-L, --location
              (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different
              location  (indicated  with  a  Location:  header  and  a  3XX
              response  code),  this  option will make curl redo the request on
              the new place.
```

If you are using `ruby`, instead of calling curl or other 3rd party tools, you may cat to use something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
# Must be somedomain.net instead of somedomain.net/, otherwise, it will throw exception.
Net::HTTP.start("somedomain.net") do |http|
    resp = http.get("/flv/sample/sample.flv")
    open("sample.flv", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
end
puts "Done."
```

Check this answer from where the example came out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263547/1135424

Comment: I try this approuch. But the `resp.body` returns only `302 Found` in to the body.

Comment: @SinésioNeto try using `curl -L http....` from the command line to check if that works

Comment: I try. But not works. Well, it's ok. I use a WebDriver like Selenium to do this. Thanks for reply!