# File download - cannot open pdf file: permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3

I need do allow user to download pdf files directly from s3 bucket. 
I figured out a method, which works correctly, but I cannot open downloaded files, getting `Permission denied`.

If I do it from console, everything is fine, and I can open downloaded pdf files afterwards.

Here's my method

```
  def download_pdf
    pdf_url = @file.pdf_url
    f = open(pdf_url)
    FileUtils.mv(f.path, "#{@file.id}.pdf")
  end
```

What can be wrong? I tried to close `TempFile`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33746205/6733955), but it didn't help

Comment: Are the files on S3 public (yes: just use the link and let them download; no: use `send_data` to access and send)? Are you uploading them there with ActiveStorage to begin with?

Comment: No, they are not. And I don't want to use `send_data` since I try to avoid streaming

Comment: If you compare the file sizes between what you can pull from the command line and what's saved with your `download_pdf` function, are they the same?