# Ruby Net::HTTP::Get and JSON responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to connect to an API and retrieve the json results with my rails app, however it doesn't seem to work.

Take for example:

```
@request = Net::HTTP::Get.new "http://example.com/?search=thing&format=json"
```

When I try the url in my browser it works! and I get JSON data, however when I try that in Ruby the body is nil.

```
>> y @request
--- !ruby/object:Net::HTTP::Get 
body: 
body_stream: 
header: 
  accept: 
  - "*/*"
  user-agent: 
  - Ruby
method: GET
path: http://example.com/?search=thing&format=json
request_has_body: false
response_has_body: true
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to actually **send** the request and retrieve a response object, like this:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response("example.com","/?search=thing&format=json")
puts response.body //this must show the JSON contents
```

Regards!

PS: While using ruby's HTTP lib, [this page](http://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet/) has some useful examples.

Comment: That worked mostly, the method takes two arguments and no protocol: `Net::HTTP.get_response("example.com", "/?search=thing&format=json")`

Answer (score 45):

I usually use open-uri

```
require 'open-uri'
content = open("http://your_url.com").read
```

`

Comment: Note unless you can be certain the url cannot have been maliciously crafted (e.g. by user input) something like `content = URI.parse('http://your_url.com').read` is safer. See https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_security.html#securityopen